# Add event Keycode to my dropdown menu with nuxt-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have an input :

```
  <input v-model="search" keyup: placeholder="Bruxelles, Namur, Gesves,..."/>
  <ul  class="searchList" id="searchlistId">
    <li  v-for="(commune, index) in filteredCommunes" :key="index"><nuxt-link class="linky" :to="{ path: '/communes/'+commune.Commune }">{{ commune.Commune }}</nuxt-link></li>
  </ul>
```

And my js methods :

```
  pressedEnter: function(e) {
      var checklist = document.getElementById('searchlistId').getElementsByTagName('li').length >= 1;
      if(checklist == true){
        var secondCheck = document.getElementById('searchlistId').getElementsByTagName('li').length;
        if(secondCheck == 1){
          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            function recup(){
              return document.getElementsByClassName('linky').getAttribute("href");
            }
            recup();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

just would like to press "Enter" and redirect to my href link. 
Thx !

Comment: I'd recommend looking at vue-shortkey: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-shortkey

Comment: My method works but I don't know how I can redirect or locate with nuxt-link. But shortkey is great.